# Typescript Type 'XX' is not assignable to type import("/Volumes/D/test").XX'.ts(2322)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, typescript-generics

I have created Code which will override the default config for the Class but I am getting weird error `Type 'IConfig' is not assignable to type 'import("/Volumes/D/www/js/tsc_1/test").IConfig'.ts(2322)`

I cannot assign the same variable TYPE to another variable. please check the screenshots

```
export default interface IPlugin {
  setConfig<T>(config: T): T
}

export interface IConfig {
  port: number
}

const _config: IConfig = {
  port: 7001
}

class Server implements IPlugin {

  public config : IConfig
  constructor() {
    this.config = _config
  }

  setConfig<IConfig>(configNew: IConfig) {
    this.config = configNew
    // ERROR - Type 'IConfig' is not assignable to type 'import("/Volumes/D/www/js/tsc_1/test").IConfig'.ts(2322)

    return configNew
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Aman, are you sure you are importing it correctly? Could you provide the syntax of your import? It should be smth like import { StringValidator } from "./StringValidator";

Comment: Hello Maria, I just created a demo please check https://repl.it/@AmanBansal1/tsnodetypeerror Just click the run button and wait you will see the error

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed it like this. Please note, that I moved the definition of the generic type to the IPlugin itself and specified the type, when extending:

```
export interface IConfig {
  port: number
}

export declare interface IPlugin<T> {
setConfig(config: T): T
}

const _config: IConfig = {
  port: 7001
}

class Server implements IPlugin<IConfig> {

  public serverConfig : IConfig
  constructor() {
    this.serverConfig = _config
  }

  setConfig(config: IConfig) : IConfig {
    this.serverConfig = config
    return config
  }
}

[Playground][1]

  [1]: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=24&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQGEIl0EBzOAbwCg45JYAuOJAVwFsAjNGgXxo1QjeABNg2ADaYoeZKgw48%20AAqS25ZAB4AKgD5qNAM7AYxUhQAU2EmXIsdASgf9BNpEfgB9d3ZZFbCjgAXkN6ERYAdgAGaIBGVxopTCMjOABlNAA3NEQOMElgDmAUNNV1TSQtAItyA1o6BjYuSQRsOBMoHKhzOzh-XopG908oNmwYaEtHMPo4GAALBCMAOk7uwcpQn0DyRoFGkzNd612B3Znz2tn6ReW17LRNkLhfIbm4WRg2KCRX3f2riAA
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you explain to me the reason why my code did not work, please?

Comment: @AmanBansal Because this is how the Generic Class works https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#generic-classes